# Execute AJAX call after AJAX Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

AJAX itself is pretty new to me, and while I can, for the most part, muddle my through and figure things out, this one has plagued me for a few days.

I have a page that is split into 2 columns.  On the left is a list of jobs shown in a table.  When a table row is clicked, the details of the selected job are loaded via ajax on the right side of the page by way of this script:

```
$(".jobTable").on("click", "tr", function() {
  var job_id = $("td:first a.ajaxCall", this).attr("rel");
  $("#jobDetails").html("Loading...");

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "jobs/jobdetails.php",
    data: {
      'id': job_id
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $("#jobDetails").html(data);
      $('#validation').html("");
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

This works fine by itself.

I wanted to add a dropdown menu that would allow sorting between open jobs, completed jobs, jobs waiting to be invoiced, and all jobs.  I accomplished this by simply making 4 separate pages with the appropriate SELECT statements and used this function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#jobSorter").change(function() {
    $("select option:selected").each(function() {

      if ($(this).attr("value") == "open-jobs") {
        $.ajax({
          url: "jobs/open-jobs.php",
          success: function(data) {
            $("#activeJobTable").html(data);
          },
          error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus);
            alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
          }
        });
      }

      if ($(this).attr("value") == "closed-jobs") {
        $.ajax({
          url: "jobs/closed-jobs.php",
          success: function(data) {
            $("#activeJobTable").html(data);
          },
          error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus);
            alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
          }
        });
      }

      if ($(this).attr("value") == "waiting-for-invoice") {
        $.ajax({
          url: "jobs/waiting-for-invoice.php",
          success: function(data) {
            $("#activeJobTable").html(data);
          },
          error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus);
            alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
          }
        });
      }
      if ($(this).attr("value") == "all-jobs") {
        $.ajax({
          url: "jobs/all-jobs.php",
          success: function(data) {
            $("#activeJobTable").html(data);
          },
          error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus);
            alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }).change();
});
```

This also works fine by itself, but as soon as I started loading the tables through ajax, it no longer responded to this script.  Nothing at all happens when I click on the table.  Through a bit of research, I thought the answer relied on my putting the first function into under "complete:" within the selector script, but all that happens then is the tables fail to load.

How can I keep the functionality of loading the job details while using the select menu to load the job lists?

Edit:  Here is the HTML for the page on which all this is happening:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4" id="jobList">

    <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="jobSorter">View Only:</label>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <select class="form-control" name="jobSorter" id="jobSorter">
            <option value="open-jobs">Open Jobs</option>
            <option value="closed-jobs">Closed Jobs</option>
            <option value="waiting-for-invoice">Waiting for Invoice</option>
            <option value="all-jobs">All Jobs</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div id="activeJobTable" </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12" id="validation"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div id='jobDetails'>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And the open-jobs.php page (the rest are all the same, only the query changes):

```
<?php require 'libraries/database.php'; $query="SELECT jobs.*, customers.cust_name, customers.id FROM `jobs`
INNER JOIN customers ON jobs.customer = customers.id
WHERE status != 'Completed' ORDER by job_id" ; $jobs=$ mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error . __LINE__); ?>



<table class="table table-hover jobTable" data-link="row">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-md-2">Job #</th>

      <th class="col-md-4">Customer Name</th>

      <th class="col-md-6">Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php while ($row=m ysqli_fetch_array($jobs)) { $jobid=$ row[ 'job_id']; $query="SELECT * FROM parts WHERE job = '$jobid' AND status != 'In Stock'" ; $result=m ysqli_query($mysqli, $query); $partrows=m ysqli_num_rows($result); if ($partrows>0) { $highlight = 'warning'; } else { $highlight = ''; } echo '
    <tr class="' . $highlight . '" id="row'.$row['job_id'].'">'; echo '
      <td>
        <a class="ajaxCall" href="#" rel="' . $row['job_id'] . '"></a>' . $row['job_id'] . '</td>'; echo '
      <td>' . $row['cust_name'] . '</td>'; echo '
      <td class="col-lg-2">' . $row['description'] . '</td>'; echo '</tr>'; } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: We probably should see your html markup to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Edited my question to include it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to change

```
$("#jobSorter").change(function() {
$("select option:selected").each(function() {

  if ($(this).attr("value") == "open-jobs") {
```

To

```
$("#jobSorter").change(function() {

  if ($(this).val() == "open-jobs") {
```

You don't need an event on each selected option. When the `jobSorter` is changed, `$(this).val()` will hold the selected value. I don't know if that's the root of the problem, but the way you did it seems wrong.

So

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#jobSorter").change(function() {

  if ($(this).val() == "open-jobs") {
    $.ajax({
      url: "jobs/open-jobs.php",
      success: function(data) {
        $("#activeJobTable").html(data);
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Status: " + textStatus);
        alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
      }
    });
  }

  if ($(this).val() == "closed-jobs") {
    $.ajax({
      url: "jobs/closed-jobs.php",
      success: function(data) {
        $("#activeJobTable").html(data);
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Status: " + textStatus);
        alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
      }
    });
  }

  if ($(this).val() == "waiting-for-invoice") {
    $.ajax({
      url: "jobs/waiting-for-invoice.php",
      success: function(data) {
        $("#activeJobTable").html(data);
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Status: " + textStatus);
        alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
      }
    });
  }
  if ($(this).val() == "all-jobs") {
    $.ajax({
      url: "jobs/all-jobs.php",
      success: function(data) {
        $("#activeJobTable").html(data);
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Status: " + textStatus);
        alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
      }
    });
  }
 });
});
```

Because you are loading tables to the DOM after you need event delgation, so you need to change

`$(".jobTable").on("click", "tr", function() {`

to

`$(document).on('click','.jobTable tr",function() {`

Comment: It doesn't fix it, but it does look nicer and more efficient.  Updated, thanks!

Comment: I added a comment. I read more clearly your issue. It's because you are adding the tables and trying to listen for click on them. Read the part in event delegation on http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Namely: "Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. ... The document element is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready."

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, but unfortunately it's not working.  Still nothing happens when I click the table row (yes I fixed the quote).  Is there a reason it wouldn't work by putting it in the complete section of the ajax call?  It seems like it would still be waiting for everything to finish before running?

Comment: Is this `<div id="activeJobTable" </div>` really like this in your code?

Comment: Can you see the ajax request being sent via Firebug or some other tool when you click the rows? That way we know either the event isn't firing or the data isn't loading.

Comment: Indeed it was.  Good catch!  Also, I just found a solution.  It's a bit of a work around, but instead of loading the tables through ajax, I put them all on the same page and just hide them.  Then I altered the jobSorter to just hide and show depending on the selection.

Comment: I wouldn't give up. But if the event was firing, i.e. you saw the request, then the issue with the injecting part. If it wasn't sending the request, then it's an issue with the listener. Throwing the DOM up all at once isn't a bad idea, as long as you aren't loading a bunch of needless images. The HTML size is most likely minimal, but images can kill load times especially when they are images the user may never see.

Comment: If I could debug the whole thing on a page at once I could tell better, but without it's tough. Also, if your div wasn't closed, that could have been causing the issues. Some browsers aren't smart enough to fix that.

Comment: I cannot believe this.  I went back to check in firebug and I happened to notice a tiny movement in the scrollbar where the table is located.  It was loading the whole time!  The css is just messed up somewhere so it's pushing it underneath the table.  *facepalm*  You've been awesome anyhow, Leeish!  I'm marking your answer as accepted because you undoubtedly improved my code.